# Powershell dbatools - use CMS to get server name

Tags: sql, powershell, dbatools

forum.... still wkg on my POS skills. using dbatools.. I'm trying to run some informational queries, against multiple SQL instances.  Is there a way to derive/use the server name from CMS to initialize the $server variable?  How could I accomplish.  I'm using:

```
Get-DbaRegisteredServer -SqlInstance CMSServer
```

There is a -ServerName parameter that contains the server name.  How could I use it to do this, against each server (or any better way I'm open for)

```
Import-Module dbatools
$servers = "localhost\instance1" # this would be all the Live servers
get-dbadatabase -SqlInstance $servers -ExcludeDatabase master, model, msdb, tempdb | Select SqlInstance, Name, RecoveryModel, Compatibility, Owner, PageVerify, TargetRecoveryTime, IsReadCommittedSnapshotOn, SnapshotIsolationState, @{l="QueryStoreState";e={$_.QueryStoreOptions.ActualState}} | Export-Csv -Path c:\bin\databasestatus.csv
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

The output of `Get-DbaRegisteredServer` is suitable for passing directly into `Get-DbaDatabase` (which accepts a collection of SQL Server instances).

```
$servers = Get-DbaRegisteredServer -sqlinstance CMSServer;
Get-DbaDatabase -SqlInstance $servers -excludesystem | Select-object SqlInstance, Name, RecoveryModel, Compatibility, Owner, PageVerify, TargetRecoveryTime, IsReadCommittedSnapshotOn, SnapshotIsolationState, @{l="QueryStoreState";e={$_.QueryStoreOptions.ActualState}} | Export-Csv -notypeinfo -Path c:\bin\databasestatus.csv
```